# What do we specify in "mainWindowUrl" property in .testcafe-electron-rc for executable electron apps like atom/vscode?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, electron, e2e-testing, testcafe

I was looking at https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-electron repository.
To automate electron apps using testcafe, I see we need to provide "mainWindowUrl" in .testcafe-electron-rc . Regular electron apps have index.html files in it which I can pass to mainWindowUrl but I'm not sure what should we pass for executable electron apps like atom.exe/vscode.exe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestCafe will show a list of URLs opened during the app initialization time if it fails to find the main window URL. You can specify an empty string as a value of `mainWindowUrl`, wait until TestCafe shows an error and use links from the displayed list.

Comment: Thank you Andrey

Answer (score 2):

To test executable electron applications you should configure the 'testcafe-browser-provider-plugin' in another way. See the [Testing an Executable Electron Application](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-electron#testing-an-executable-electron-application) section for more information.